# How to resolve an error 404 for django-social?

Tags: django, facebook, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, python-social-auth

I want to be able to login through social media. Followed all the steps (registered app), the login works just fine but does not go through because django does not recognize my url.

This is my call to the api endpoint

```
facebookLogin(token: string):any{
    return this.http.post(environment.api + 'fblogin/', {token:this.token}).subscribe(
      (onSucess:any) => {
        localStorage.setItem(this._tokenKey, onSucess.token)
      }, onFail => {
        console.log(onFail)

      }
    );
  }
```

But I get the following error : **POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fblogin/ 404 (Not Found)**. From this I know there to be something wrong with my django urls. And indeed going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fblogin/ gave me a page not found error and that it tried to match several other urls.

However I can't see what is wrong with my urls

**URLS in my app**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token
from social_django import urls

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'fblogin/', include(urls)),
    url(r'auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'refresh/', refresh_jwt_token)
]
```

**URLS in my project**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('Backend.api.urls'))
]
```

Other URLS like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ do work. I also am under the impression that all of my settings are in order.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that I might be because of the order and way in which you have defined URLs.py try the below format

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token
from social_django import urls

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^fblogin/', include(urls)),
    url(r'^auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^refresh/', refresh_jwt_token)
] + router.urls
```